# Python ServiceManager package generates list index out of range

Tags: python, py2exe

I have created a Service in python with ServiceManage Package and I'm building it  with py2exe.

So, When I Try to install, this error appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updaterguardian.py", line 129, in <module>
  File "win32serviceutil.pyc", line 549, in HandleCommandLine
  File "win32serviceutil.pyc", line 488, in GetServiceClassString
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Im not understanding why.
My windows is 8 with 64bits. Is there any relation?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am havin the same problem, building with pyInstaller